# Retrieve all rows in table 'A' matching a set of rows in table 'B'

Tags: sql, mysql

I've got two tables :

One with items :

| id | name | other properties... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Fantastic Item | (...) |
| 2 | Wonderful Item | (...) |
| 3 | Marvelous Item | (...) |

The second with their state (expressed by multiple boolean) :

| item_id | state_var_name | state_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PAID | true |
| 1 | READY_TO_SHIP | false |
| 1 | SHIPPED | false |
| 2 | PAID | true |
| 2 | MORE_INFOS_NEEDED | true |
| 2 | READY_TO_SHIP | false |
| 2 | SHIPPED | false |
| 2 | CANCELLED | true |
| 3 | PAID | true |
| 3 | READY_TO_SHIP | false |
| 3 | SHIPPED | true |

(Note that all "state var names" do not necessarily exist for all items.)

Here is my question :
What is the **fastest** way to retrieve/count all items matching several states criteria ?
For instance : *Retrieve all items with 'PAID' = true AND 'CANCELLED' = (false or non-existent)*.

I tried the two requests below but they are too slow (several [tens of] seconds each) :
(My 'items' table has about 800,000 rows, the 'states' table about 13,000,000.)

First try :

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM items
WHERE 
    EXISTS (
        SELECT item_id FROM states 
        WHERE item_id = items.id AND state_var_name = 'PAID' AND state_value = 1
    )
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT item_id FROM states 
        WHERE item_id = items.id AND state_var_name = 'CANCELLED' AND state_value = 1
    )
```

Second try (a tiny bit quicker but still very slow) :

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM items
    LEFT JOIN states AS s1
    ON s1.item_id = items.id AND s1.state_var_name = 'PAID' AND s1.state_value = 1
    LEFT JOIN states AS s2
    ON s2.item_id = items.id AND s2.state_var_name = 'CANCELLED' AND s2.state_value = 1
WHERE s1.state_value IS NOT NULL AND s2.state_value IS NULL
```

I'm pretty sure it's possible to write a faster query to do this, but I'm not comfortable enough with SQL to do it.

EDIT : The table 'states' has an index with item_id + state_var_name + state_value.

Comment: What indexes do you have? I think a composite index on `(item_id, state_value, state_var_name)` would improve performance.

Comment: @Barmar This index already exists.

Comment: In the second code, replace the first `LEFT JOIN` with `INNER JOIN`. Then you can get rid of `s1.state_value IS NOT NULL`. Inner joins are generally faster than outer joins.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks ! I didn't know that. The query is now two seconds faster. Unfortunately it is still very very slow (28s).

Comment: Play around with reordering the columns in the multi-column index. You could also try using a CTE that extracts just the rows with `state_value = 1 AND state_var_name IN ('PAID', 'CANCELLED')`.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you VERY much ! I didn't think while creating the index and made it start with item_id... Now that it starts with state_var_name, it is much quicker. Almost instantaneous ! Thanks again ! If you copy your last comment in an answer, I could mark this question as resolved.

Comment: You post an answer showing specifically what you did. I don't need the rep.

Answer (score 0):

As Barmar said in the comments, the issue came from the index.

My initial index was made according to this order: item_id > state_var_name > state_value.
The requests with this index was very slow (tens of seconds).

I've made a new index according to this order : state_var_name > state_value > item_id.
The requests are now almost instantaneous.

It's better to start the index with state_var_name and state_value since it allows to check the 'state' condition before retrieving the item_id.